# setting CORS while creating bucket in AWS s3 using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a bucket dynamically through angular.

I can create the bucket manually and upload images to it through angular but that is not what I want. I want to be able to create a bucket through angular code and set the CORS configuration as it throws a CORS error. The CORS configuration can be set manually in AWS after the creation of a bucket. I am trying to find out how to set the CORS through angular code.

```
 const bucket = new S3(
  {
    accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
    region: 'eu-west-1'
  }
);

const params = {
  Bucket: 'examplebucket',
     CreateBucketConfiguration: {
     LocationConstraint: 'eu-west-1'
   }
};
bucket.createBucket(params, function (err, data) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Error Obtained: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes @ExplosionPills I get CORS error. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I know how to manually set the CORS for a bucket, but how do I do it through my code while creating each bucket

Comment: Is this an issue with creating the bucket or putting/getting objects from a newly created bucket?

Comment: This is an issue with creating buckets